# TypeError: the JSON object must be str, not 'bytes' - Python - fixer.io

Tags: python, fixer.io

I have this code:

```
from flask import Flask, flash, redirect, render_template, request, session, abort
import os
import json
from urllib.request import urlopen

tmpl_dir = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)), 'templates')
app = Flask(__name__, template_folder=tmpl_dir)

def getExchangeRates():
    rates = []
    response = urlopen('https://data.fixer.io/api/latest?access_key=my_key')
    data = response.read()
    rdata = json.loads(data, parse_float=float)

    rates.append( rdata['rates']['USD'] )
    rates.append( rdata['rates']['GBP'] )
    rates.append( rdata['rates']['HKD'] )
    rates.append( rdata['rates']['AUD'] )
    return rates

@app.route("/")
def index():
    rates = getExchangeRates()
    return render_template('test.html',**locals())      

@app.route("/hello")
def hello():
    return "Hello World!"
```

But it throws me this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/usio_flask/lib/python3.4/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2292, in wsgi_app
response = self.full_dispatch_request()
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/usio_flask/lib/python3.4/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1815, in full_dispatch_request
rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/usio_flask/lib/python3.4/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1718, in handle_user_exception
reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/usio_flask/lib/python3.4/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 35, in reraise
raise value
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/usio_flask/lib/python3.4/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1813, in full_dispatch_request
rv = self.dispatch_request()
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/usio_flask/lib/python3.4/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1799, in dispatch_request
return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
File "app/app.py", line 23, in index
rates = getExchangeRates()
File "app/app.py", line 13, in getExchangeRates
rdata = json.loads(data, parse_float=float)
File "/usr/lib/python3.4/json/__init__.py", line 312, in loads
s.__class__.__name__))
TypeError: the JSON object must be str, not 'bytes'
```

The offending line is this one:

```
rdata = json.loads(data, parse_float=float)
```

I'm just trying to get some rates from `fixer.io` API, any ideas?

if **name** == "**main**":
    app.run()

Comment: `rdata = json.loads(data.decode(), parse_float=float)` ?

Comment: Thank You, You can put this as an answer if You want

Comment: Wait, it now throws AttributeError: 'HTTPResponse' object has no attribute 'json'
, anyways, I think it has to do with urllib, maybe I'll open a new question for that, Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[[Python 3.Docs]: json.**loads**(*s, *, encoding=None, cls=None, object_hook=None, parse_float=None, parse_int=None, parse_constant=None, object_pairs_hook=None, **kw*)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.loads) states:

> Deserialize s (a [str](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str), [bytes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes) or [bytearray](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytearray) instance containing a JSON document) to a Python object using this [conversion table](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/json.html#json-to-py-table).

`urllib.request.urlopen` returns a `http.client.HTTPResponse` object.

According to [[Python 3.Docs]: http.client - HTTPResponse.**read**(*[amt]*)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.client.html#http.client.HTTPResponse.read):

> Reads and returns the response body, or up to the next *amt* **bytes**.

So, in order to make this work, you have to convert the *bytes* into *str* 
(via [[Python 3.Docs]: bytes.**decode**(*encoding="utf-8", errors="strict"*)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes.decode)):

```py
rdata = json.loads(data.decode(), parse_float=float)
```

**Note**:

- Starting with *Python 3.**6***, `json.loads` is able to also handle *bytes*

Regarding your other error, I remember (as I once worked with *Flask*) that the *Response* objects only had a *json* method, if the *HTTP* status code was ***200*** (*OK*). But I'm not sure it's the same object that we're talking about, since I was using the *requests* module.

Comment: Thank You very much! Gonna look at that!